# Sequence contains no elements issue throwing after implementing Parallel.ForEach loop

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have used nested `Parallel.ForEach` loop to populate list of data. the after using `Parallel.ForEach` some time I am getting error Sequence contains no elements which is throwing from later portion of the code.

I have two section in this post. First I will post my `Parallel.ForEach` loop code

```
Parallel.ForEach(OrderWiseLineItem, data =>
                    {
                        // string Li = data1.LineItem;
                        string section = data.Section;
                        string Li = data.Lineitem;

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Li) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(section))
                        {
                            Parallel.ForEach(DistinctBroker, broker =>
                            {
                                    // for broker row .... weightage 1 (no color)
                                    
                                    Interlocked.Increment(ref rowNumber);
                                    brokerRowWeightageRowNumber = new WeightageRowNumber();
                                    brokerRowWeightageRowNumber.Section = section;
                                    brokerRowWeightageRowNumber.Lineitem = Li;
                                    brokerRowWeightageRowNumber.Broker = broker;
                                    brokerRowWeightageRowNumber.RowNumber = rowNumber;
                                    brokerRowWeightageRowNumber.Weightage = (int)RowWeightage.BrokerRow;

                                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                                        WeightageRowNumberall.Add(brokerRowWeightageRowNumber);
                                    }
                            }

                                Interlocked.Increment(ref rowNumber);
                                ConsensusRowWeightageRowNumber = new WeightageRowNumber();
                                ConsensusRowWeightageRowNumber.Section = section;
                                ConsensusRowWeightageRowNumber.Lineitem = Li;
                                ConsensusRowWeightageRowNumber.Broker = "";
                                ConsensusRowWeightageRowNumber.RowNumber = rowNumber;
                                ConsensusRowWeightageRowNumber.Weightage = (int)RowWeightage.ConsenSusRow;

                                lock (_lock)
                                {
                                    WeightageRowNumberall.Add(ConsensusRowWeightageRowNumber);
                                }


                            if (qcTrueDistin.Any(x => x.TabName.Equals(section) && x.StandardLineItem.Equals(Li)))
                            {
                                // for QC Check row .... weightage 3, if any  (yellow color)
                                Parallel.ForEach(DistinctBroker, broker =>
                                {

                    Interlocked.Increment(ref rowNumber);
                    QcRowWeightageRowNumber = new WeightageRowNumber();

                    QcRowWeightageRowNumber.Section = section;
                    QcRowWeightageRowNumber.Lineitem = Li;
                    QcRowWeightageRowNumber.Broker = broker;
                    QcRowWeightageRowNumber.RowNumber = rowNumber;
                    QcRowWeightageRowNumber.Weightage = (int)RowWeightage.QcRow;
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                    WeightageRowNumberall.Add(QcRowWeightageRowNumber);
                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

In the above code I used `Parallel.ForEach` because there was huge iteration which was taking few minute and after using `Parallel.ForEach` loop started taking few second. it was good for me but now some time I am getting *Sequence contains no elements error*.

Now here I am posting the code which is throwing error *Sequence contains no elements*.

```
if (dataBroker.Any(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FormulaLiConfig)))
{
    string formulastd = dataBroker.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FormulaLiConfig)).FirstOrDefault().FormulaLiConfig;
    List<string> stdformulalist = FormulaevaluationStandardFormula(formulastd);
    foreach (string formulatemp in stdformulalist)
    {
    if (formulatemp.Contains("~"))
    {
        string section1 = formulatemp.Split('~')[0].Trim();
        string li1 = formulatemp.Split('~')[1].Trim();

        int rowNumber1 = -1;
        rowNumber1 = WeightageRowNumberall.Where(x => x.Section.Trim().Equals(section1)
        && x.Lineitem.Trim().Equals(li1)
        && x.Broker.Equals(broker)
        && x.Weightage == (int)RowWeightage.BrokerRow).FirstOrDefault().RowNumber;

        StandardFormulaConstituents objStandardFormulaConstituents = new StandardFormulaConstituents();
        objStandardFormulaConstituents.Id = coutstdformula;
        objStandardFormulaConstituents.Constituent = formulatemp;
        objStandardFormulaConstituents.RowNumberConstituent = rowNumber1;
        coutstdformula = coutstdformula + 1;
        StandardFormulaConstituentsall.Add(objStandardFormulaConstituents);
    }
    }
}
```

Actually the exact below line throwing error Sequence contains no elements

```
rowNumber1 = WeightageRowNumberall.Where(x => x.Section.Trim().Equals(section1) && x.Lineitem.Trim().Equals(li1) 
&& x.Broker.Equals(broker) && x.Weightage == (int)RowWeightage.BrokerRow).FirstOrDefault().RowNumber;
```

I am not being able to understand the reason why some time I am getting this error Sequence contains no elements from the above line of code. `WeightageRowNumberall` is populated in `Parallel.ForEach` that is why I suspect some issue is there in `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

Please guys see my code and tell me why I am getting this error? Is `Parallel.ForEach` loop is creating issue as per my code?

Also tell me should I remove nested `Parallel.ForEach` loop and retain only outer `Parallel.ForEach` only...does it make sense?

Please guys read my code and give me some solution to restructure my code to get rid of this error *Sequence contains no elements*.

If I remove `Parallel.ForEach` and use normal `foreach` then never encounter the error *Sequence contains no elements*.

Tell me the reason if anyone understand why I am getting some time error and some time not? I am not being able to capture the reason for the error which is happening not always but some time.

Comment: Not your main problem, but your `rowNumber`s are going to be all over the place and probably inaccurate the majority of the time. `Interlocked.Increment` returns the incremented value. Store that in a *local variable* and assign *that* to the `RowNumber` property. Also using `lock` like that probably doesn't help you. You can pass a state variable into the parallel loops. Use that to build seperare lists and then combine them all at the very end.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i do not have much experience working with parallel,foreach or for. so i would like to request you that please put some sample code here what you are trying to say. see my code and show me how to rectify the area which causing issue with you approach. looking for further guidance with code sample. thanks

Comment: `rowNumber` is local one which is declared before parallel.for loop and it is incremented by `Interlocked.Increment` what you said not very clear. please show me with sample code.

Comment: you said `You can pass a state variable into the parallel loops` i do not know how to pass state variable into the parallel loops ? so my humble request please show me with code sample that how should i construct my parallel.foreach. thanks

Comment: do i need to remove nested parallel foreach ?

Comment: This: `Interlocked.Increment(ref rowNumber);` increments the `rowNumber` in the outer scope, yes. But when you call `brokerRowWeightageRowNumber.RowNumber = rowNumber` the variable will be the latest value, which may have already been incremented by another thread (due to Interlocked.Increment in each loop). I'm suggesting you at the very least use `var localRowNumber = Interlocked.Increment(ref rowNumber); brokerRowWeightageRowNumber.RowNumber =  localRowNumber;` That said there's better ways to avoid all of that (and probably the nested loops) but I don't have time to write you an answer

Comment: Any type of locking in Parallel.For/ForEach, whether explicit `lock` or via `Interlocked` or concurrent collections usually isn't a good idea and negates the benefits of the parallelism. `Parallel.For` may be better since you get an index variable from it and can use that to set your rowNumber without the interlocked. (`localRowNumber = rowNumber+index`). But like I said I don't have time for a real answer and I doubt you'll have any luck until you format your code better, it's really difficult to read and most people won't spend the time to help if you can't spend the time up front.

Comment: thanks for your answer.